# Windows keyboard input c++

Tags: c++, windows

I know for linux you can get the keyboard input by reading from /dev/input/eventX. Is there a similar way to get input in Windows? Like knowing when a key is pressed without any 3rd party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), and check the bit `0x8000` in the return value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000) {
      std::cout << "'A' key is pressed\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "'A' key is not pressed\n";
    }
    Sleep(250);
  }
}
```

You can find the list of virtual key codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes). Letters and numbers are represented by their regular corresponding (upper-case) ASCII-characters, so in this example it is just `'A'` for the <kbd>A</kbd> key. But if you'd wanted to check the <kbd>F1</kbd> key for example, you'd use `VK_F1`.